# Using Boost::optional with ->multitoken and/or ->composing()

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to use Boost to be able to pass multiple arguments or have multiple occurrences of a flag with `->multitoken` and `->composing`. However, I want this to be an optional flag using `boost::optional<>`.

Below is the basic boost example from their site, modified for my purpose. Without the `boost::optional` wrapper, everything works as expected.

`run //path/to/example:main --letter a b c` results in `a b c` being printed.

If I change options_description to be of `boost::optional` type:

`("letter", po::value<boost::optional<vector<string>>>()->multitoken()->composing(), "multiple values");`

Then `--letter a b c'` Errors with `option '--letter' only takes a single argument`

And `--letter a --letter b` Errors with `option '--letter' cannot be specified more than once`

Anyone know more about boost to be able to use both `boost::optional` and `->multitoken()`/`->composing()`? I would like to avoid removing boost::optional and adding a default value.

```
/* The simplest usage of the library.
 */

#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
namespace po = boost::program_options;

#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main(int ac, char* av[]) {
  try {
    po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
    desc.add_options()
    ("help", "produce help message")
    ("letter", po::value<vector<string>>()->multitoken()->composing(), "multiple values");

    po::variables_map vm;
    po::store(po::parse_command_line(ac, av, desc), vm);
    po::notify(vm);

    if (vm.count("help")) {
      cout << desc << "\n";
      return 0;
    }

    if (vm.count("letter")) {
      vector<string> list = vm["letter"].as<vector<string>>();
      for (size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
        cout << list[i] << " ";
      cout << '\n';
    }

  } catch (exception& e) {
    cerr << "error: " << e.what() << "\n";
    return 1;
  } catch (...) {
    cerr << "Exception of unknown type!\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between the empty vector and `boost::none` optional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplicity reduces bugs and improves maintainability.

Simplicity is usually when you reach the "sweet spot" of a library - the way it was designed. In this design, multi-token option are an extension of optionals (an optional is just like container with a maximum size of 1). The design does not expect you to layer both on top of each other.

Instead, I'd leave the code as is and consume how you want to consume it:

```
boost::optional<strings> dream_variable;
if (vm.contains("letter")) {
    auto& opt = vm.at("letter");
    if (!opt.defaulted()) {
        dream_variable = opt.as<strings>();
    }
}
```

That's improving readability by

```
using strings = std::vector<std::string>;
```

### Live Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10c11153dfcccea9)**

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/optional/optional_io.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
namespace po = boost::program_options;

#include <iostream>

int main(int ac, char* av[]) {
    using strings = std::vector<std::string>;
    try {
        po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
        desc.add_options()                   //
            ("help", "produce help message") //
            ("letter",
             po::value<strings>()          //
                 ->multitoken()            //
                 ->composing()             //
                 ->implicit_value({}, ""), //
             "multiple values");

        po::variables_map vm;
        store(parse_command_line(ac, av, desc), vm);
        notify(vm);

        boost::optional<strings> dream_variable;
        if (vm.contains("letter")) {
            auto& opt = vm.at("letter");
            if (!opt.defaulted()) {
                dream_variable = opt.as<strings>();
            }
        }

        if (dream_variable) {
            for (auto& letter : *dream_variable) {
                std::cout << " - " << letter << "\n";
            }
        } else {
            std::cout << " * none\n";
        }
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << "error: " << e.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Exception of unknown type!\n";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

With the output:

```
+ ./a.out --letter aa bb cc
 - aa
 - bb
 - cc
+ ./a.out --letter
+ ./a.out
 * none
```

Note I assumed that you wanted `implicit_value` as well, because it's the only sensible way I can imagine how `--letter` without value tokens would be different from just not specifying the option.

Comment: If this doesn't give you the control/results you need, you can always refine it using `parsed_options` info: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d05aae1b047dfa0c

Comment: Solved! Thanks so much for the explanation of the use of optional, and how that it doesn't exactly make sense with the use of another container. The extensive examples were very helpful too!