# boost::program_options option of type std::optional<string> will not compile

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

The line attempting to add_options() of type std::optional<string> results in a compile error. does boost::program_options not support this type? how are optional options managed w/ boost::program_options?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
using namespace std;
#include <boost\program_options.hpp>
using namespace boost;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
     cout << "Hello World\n" << boolalpha;

     program_options::options_description options_description("options");
     options_description.add_options()
          ("help", "please help me get this code to compile w/o error . the line below needs to be commented out for a clean compile . does boost not permit an options optional<> type ? Thank You Kindly")
          ("optional string", program_options::value<std::optional<string>>, "this option is optional")
          ;
}
```

expected clean compile and boost::program_options to support std::optional<> type

Comment: ***the line attempting to add_options() of type std::optional results in a compile error*** What error? Please add the exact text of the error message as text. No pictures of text.

Comment: After fixing the include to use / instead of \ I was able to get the errors: [https://godbolt.org/z/d85jE5nv8](https://godbolt.org/z/d85jE5nv8)

Comment: @drescherjm those are likely not the errors you (or OP) were looking for. The code was cute, but sloppy copy-paste practice (not to mention `using namespace *;` abuse :))

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call `value<>()`.

Besides, optional options are represented by either

- no value stored inside the `variable_map`
- or the default value (from the `option_description`) stored inside the `variable_map`

I explained the background in a similar situation here: [Using Boost::optional with ->multitoken and/or ->composing()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74187581/using-boostoptional-with-multitoken-and-or-composing/74194810#74194810)

Of course, you can *insist* in your case, e.g. because you want to supply `boost::none` as the default value (just making things up for the story-line, albeit far-fetched). In that case, I suggest `boost::optional` as it enjoys library support:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3627bafeb3dfc036)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main(/*int argc, char const* argv[]*/) {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    po::options_description options_description("options");
    options_description.add_options()                                                             //
        ("optional string", po::value<boost::optional<std::string>>(), "this option is optional") //
        ;
}
```

If you *must* have `std::optional<>` support you'll have to add it yourself: [Using boost::program_options with std::optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66539770/using-boostprogram-options-with-stdoptional/66548554#66548554)